# Browser won't display ejs-rendered page in response of Fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

Well, today I faced with weird (at least for me now) issue.
To summarize, I send a PUT request from user form to back. As form doesn't supports sending PUT/DELETE requests directly, I use a script for doing this job for me.

```
let form = document.getElementById("form");

if (form) {
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
    if (this.dataset.id !== "create") {
      ev.preventDefault();

      let formData = {};

      Array.from(this.getElementsByTagName("input")).forEach((inputElement) => {
        formData[inputElement.name] = inputElement.value;
      });

      fetch(this.action, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        alert(data.message);
        window.location = '/user';
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert("FETCH: Server error", err);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

then, on server side, I receive a request, and do some validation with an 'JOI' framework, and if there're any errors in request body, servers' PUT request handler returned and with 'next' passes control and the error details to the last middleware, that should handle it and render an error page for user with an error number and a description:

```
  .put(async (req, res, next) => {

    // Control point 1

    const id = req.params.id;

    /* Joi validation */
    const { error } = userValidation(req.body);
    if (error) {
      return next({ type: "JOI", message: error });
    }


    let user = {};

    try {
      user = await User.findById(id).exec();
    } catch (error) {
      return next({ type: "DB", message: error });
    }

    const userUpdate = Object.assign(user, req.body);

    try {
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, userUpdate);
    } catch (error) {
      return next({ type: "DB", message: error });
    }

    res.json({ message: "updated" });
  })
```

next ->>

```
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

  let errorStatus = 500;
  let errorDescription = '';
  let errorMessage = 'Something broke in EXPRESS!'; 
  
  const statusCodes = {
    DB: [500, 'DB Error'],
    JOI: [400, 'Joi Validation Error'],
  }

  if (statusCodes[err.type]) {
    errorStatus = statusCodes[err.type][0];
    errorDescription = statusCodes[err.type][1];
    errorMessage = err.message
  }

  // Control point 2
  
  res.status(errorStatus).render('./userpages/error', {
    title: "Error page",
    errorStatus,
    errorDescription,
    errorMessage,
  })
})
```

At least it supposed to be like that.
When there's no errors it works as expected, but otherwise, when there an error's thrown, the problem occurs, and I cannot make browser to reflect an error page express sent to it.

All error handling logic works flawlessly on GET and POST request, 'next' middleware renders an error page and browser shows it properly, as long as frontend script not being used, but as soon I'm trying to use POST/DELETE it fails.

Also, what weirdly, that of course I can check I get the request at express handler at 'control point 1', it works as expected, then I can trace it successfully passing control to 'next' part,
where I can log it in 'control point 2', then even rendering part of middleware works well and actually sends error page to browser, where I can see that whole page in devtools/network/response tab, but nevertheless browser won't whow it.

I tried to restrict fetch request to just only FETCH part:

```
      fetch(this.action, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
      });
```

but it has no effect. Just nothing happens. Browser keep staying on user update form. Despite I can see response page from the back on the response tab.

Response headers are:

```
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
3194
Content-Type:
text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:
Thu, 17 Aug 2023 17:06:50 GMT
Etag:
W/"c7a-+RH1COmYevyB5uHV+N+w/gV7ydM"
Keep-Alive:
timeout=5
X-Powered-By:
Express
```

while FETCH request itself returns:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:3100/user/64dcec6a0350dba2f994565e
Request Method:
PUT
Status Code:
400 Bad Request
Remote Address:
[::1]:3100
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I also had an idea that '400 Bad Request' that browser gets from next middleware may prevent error page displaying, but when I sent 200 nothing changed.

What are details I'm missing here?
And is there an approach it can be implemented using common express error handling as I do for all other cases, and it works.

Comment: **Do not edit your post to say you solved it**. Either delete your post because you were able to solve it yourself just fine and so you posted it too soon, or **post an answer** and then accept that a few days from now. That's the whole point of this site works: there's a question post, and then folks (including potentially you yourself) write answer posts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. I just had to handle server response with fetch:

```
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          response.text().then((errorPage) => {
            document.body.innerHTML = errorPage;
          });
        } else {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            alert(data.message);
            window.location = '/user';
          })
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert("FETCH: Server error", err);
      });
```

It works now though I had to use nesting thanables to implement the logic of showing an error page in case of error or redirecting to another page if request was handled correctly. Was it OK for such a case or it could be solved more clear or elegant way ? Please let me know if someone has any ideas relating the issue.